# Efficiently determining intersection of 3D boxes

Tags: collision-detection, physics, simulation, intersection

I am trying to develop an algorithm to determine wether two boxes (but I think it applies to any convex polyhedron) intersect. I'm gonna use this for collision detection.

Each polyhedron's state is represented as the translation vector of it's center of mass, and an orientation matrix (3x3 orthonormal representing the object-space coordinates).

My general idea is to take each face of the two polyhedrons, figure out the planar equation for it (by applying the polyhedron orientation and translation components) , and go over each of the vertices of the other polyhedron, and determine whether all of them are on the same side of the plane, and if they are, I determine that the two objects do not intersect.

As to the collision detection part, I will detect whether they intersect and if they did I would binary search the moment when they touch, and try at that moment to find the vertex of collision by finding the vertex of the other object which is closest to the plane I found earlier to determine the point of contact.

My question is, whether this algorithm is correct, and if it is, is it an overkill? Could I somehow spare some checks, or speed up the process?

Answer (score 1):

I think your algorithm is correct and as efficient as you are going to get. To be clear you need to check every face of *both* polyhedra and if you find *any* case where every vertex of the other polyhedra is on the "outside" of the infinite plane then no intersection.

For performance:

1 precompute enclosing spheres so you can do an initial 'coarse' check

2 precompute all of your outward normal vectors and carry them through your rotation transformation - should be cheaper than doing a bunch of cross products,

Finding the "point" of intersection I think can be done using the same algorithm and presuming a linear interpolation between intersecting and non intersecting states and seeking a solution where one vertex is exactly on one plane.